# Where can I ask a question about finding modules that meet certain requirements?

Tags: support, faq, questions

I have a list of requirements for a module, but I don't know which modules meet these criteria.

Is this question appropriate on Drupal Answers? Where should I ask about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is a site that does just that. They even have a [drupal](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal) tag which (on March 11, 2022) is used from 16 questions.

Please note that like anywhere else on Stack Exchange, questions like "what's the best …" are not answerable and will be closed. A software recommendation question should both provide precise requirements (what platform it needs to run on, what **specific functionality** is absolutely needed, etc.) and explain for **what purpose** the software will be used. Precise requirements avoid getting answers that won't be useful because the software lacks a critical feature. A statement of purpose or user story allows users who answer to look for the best fit for the task. You are strongly encouraged to read the [question quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) before asking a question on Software Recommendations.

Software Recommendations Stack Exchange accepts questions about general-purpose software, development tools and libraries, as well as more specialized software. Even so, you are encouraged to read and follow the Software Recommendations Stack Exchange question quality guidelines.

Note that hardware (what to run the software on) and hosting (who can run the software for you) are off-topic on Software Recommendations. Hardware recommendations can be asked on [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).